# username=forms.CharFeild(max_length=100) AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'CharFeild'

Tags: python

I am getting this error:

> username=forms.CharFeild(max_length=100) AttributeError: module
>   'django.forms' has no attribute 'CharFeild'

Here is my code:

```
from django import forms

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    username=forms.CharFeild(max_length=100)
    password=forms.CharFeild(max_length=100)
    email=forms.CharFeild(max_length=100)
    phone=forms.CharFeild(max_length=100)
```

Comment: "Feild" is spelt "Field".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: you should write `CharField` not `CharFeild`.